# Use the same object between activities

Tags: java, android, object, android-activity

I have tried a lot of different ways to use the same object in different classes. I want to do this because I want the data to be stored in this object. 
But no matter what I do, it hust wont be stored when I press the "back" button on the phone and then go back.

I am sending a bundle with the object to the second activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TrainingDays.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("programObject", program);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

And I am receiving the object like this:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
program = (Program) bundle.getSerializable("programObject");
```

I can use the object just fine, but I every time I switch back to another activity, the object is clean from data. Am I doing something wrong here or could it be something else that causes this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show method your creating the object in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the correct way to manage objects. If you do not need to write the object on a File I would suggest to switch to `Parcelable`. About your problem, if you want to pass back the object, you can use the pair `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult`

Comment: It sounds like @user68621 is just trying to maintain the state of the previous intent. So when they navigate back one activity they still have a reference to the object.

Comment: he has activity A and B. He changes the object in B and he wants A to read those changes.

Comment: The object should be written to a file later on, so i need it to implement Serializable. Can I still solve my problem using the startActivityForResult and onActivityResult?

Comment: if I have not misunderstood what you need, it should. Simply modifiy the object, put it in a intent and pass back to the starting activity. In the OnActivityResult read again the object. At least you should give it a try

Comment: I will. So the OnActivityResult should be in the parent class and the startActivityForResult in the "child" class.. right?

Comment: wrong. you have to override onActivityResult in the same class that call startActivityForResult. Your child class has to call setResult and finish in order to trigger startActivityForResult. Those are basic android concept. I would like to suggest you to read a bit of documentation

Comment: Okay i got it to work now.. By combinating yours and inner_class7's answers. But since you pointed me in the right direction first, i'll accept your answer. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Override the `onBackPressed()` method of Activity and use @blackbelt 's combination of `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()`

You can see an example on the developer page http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

onBackPressed()  controls going back to the previous activity you could create a new `Intent` in the `onBackPressed()`, then a create a `Bundle` and Put the Bundle in the `setResult()` method as such `setResult(RESULT_OK, mBundle);` and Bundle  Object will get passed back the previous activity.

in Short

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent data  = new Intent();
    Bundle newBundle = new Bundle();
    newBundle.putParcelable("MyObject", mObject);// must extend Parcelable on Object class
    data.putBundleExtra("ObjectBundle", newBundle);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    finish();
 }
```

Comment: Then use  the ObjectBundle Key to refer to the Bundle and the MyObject key to refer to the parcelable in `onActivityResult()` and